# Вывести свойство типа файл

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день нужно вывести свойство типа файл и строка

Вот начало кода положено

```
  CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');

$arSelect = Array();
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>1);
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(1), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arFields);      // здесь есть
    echo '</pre>';
    $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arProps);       // здесь ничего нет
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: А почитать документацию по работе с полем типа "файл" не судьба?

Comment: @NikolajSarry Может пытался и не получается так как мало опыта ? И решил обратиться к товарищам

Comment: @Andry ну вообще у вас код верный и он должен вернуть все свойства, странно что у вас ни чего нету в `$arProps` могу только предположить что или нету инфоблока с id = 1 или нету у этого инфоблока свойств

Comment: @ИгорьБраницкий у меня свойство элемента типа файл вывод все кроме ссылки на сам файл

Comment: @Andry правильно потому что в свойстве хранится ID файла, а по этому ID вы можете получить уже ссылку с помощью методов класса CFile.

Answer (score 2):

```
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$arSelect = Array();
$arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>1, "CODE"=>"vide", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    $arProps = $ob->GetProperties();
    echo CFile::GetPath($arProps["BACK_IMG"]["VALUE"]);
}
```

Коряво но я еще не закончил страницу и буду дорабатывать код. Но это решило мою проблему

Answer (score 2):

```
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$arSelect = ['IBLOCK_ID', 'CODE', 'PROPERTY_BACK_IMG'];
$arFilter = ["IBLOCK_ID"=>1, "CODE"=>"vide", "ACTIVE"=>"Y"];
$res = \CIBlockElement::GetList([], $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    echo \CFile::GetPath($arProps[PROPERTY_BACK_IMG_VALUE"]);
}
```

Использовать $ob->GetProperties() - это уже когда совсем нечего терять.